# Does Batch Norm require constant batch size?

Tags: deep-learning

[Batch normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03167.pdf) uses a mini-batch mean and variance to normalize layer output. If I train a network with batch size, say 100, but then want to use the trained network on single-shot predictions (batch size 1), should I expect to run into problems? 
Should I penalize the batch norm layer to converge towards the identity transform during learning to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no problems when doing that, at test time the batch normalization layer just scales and shifts the inputs, with factors learned at training time.

Comment: If my test input is an outlier, wouldn't it be incorrectly centered? Is it a better idea to set batch norm to use the mean / cov of the full training set?

Comment: Ah I see. You are saying that we do not recompute the mini-batch mean and covariance at test time. That makes sense.